# Execute .bind event onLoad for Jquery Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using [kelvin lucks jquery date picker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/).

I have a start and end date picker set up so that when the start date is selected it assigns that same date to the end date and the end date insures that its calendar does not allow selecting of any dates before the start date.

Works great except if you select the end date without touching the start date you are able to set an end date before the start date. Not good!

```
$(function()
{
    $('.date-pick').datePicker({startDate:'2000-01-01', clickInput:true})

        $('#start-date').bind('dpClosed', function(e, selectedDates) {
                var d = selectedDates[0];
                if (d) {
            d = new Date(d);
            $('#end-date').dpSetStartDate(d.addDays(0).asString()).dpSetSelected(d.asString()).val($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Because I am prefilling the input fields using PHP, all I want to do is trigger `$('#end-date').dpSetStartDate` so that the end date updates when the document loads. At the moment it only updates on `$('#start-date').bind('dpClosed', function(e, selectedDates) {`

How do I do this?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: `$(function() {});` is a shortcut for binding to document.ready. Everything inside of it will not execute until the document is ready. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry... I confused myself. All I want to do is trigger $('#end-date').dpSetStartDate so that the end date updates when the document loads. At the moment it only updates on $('#start-date').bind('dpClosed', function(e, selectedDates) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just trigger the event unfortunately, because you're trying on `selectedDates` from the arguments...however there's another way to get that data: [`$('#start-date').dpGetSelected()`](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/documentation.html).  By using this you can then [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event whenever you want (immediately) to update the `#end-date` range, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datePicker({startDate:'2000-01-01', clickInput:true});
    $('#start-date').bind('dpClosed', function(e, selectedDates) {
      var d = $('#start-date').dpGetSelected()[0];
      if (d) {
       d = new Date(d);
       $('#end-date').dpSetStartDate(d.addDays(0).asString()).dpSetSelected(d.asString()).val($(this).val());
     }
   }).trigger('dpClosed'); //call that event handler we just bound
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hyeXM/).

Comment: Fantastic!!! I thought there might have been a smarter way to do this but that's just mindblowingly amazing!Its exactly what I needed. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to make sure the date the user enters in the end date field is on or after the date they enter in the start date field.

To do this, you'll need to bind to the dpClosed event for both of the date pickers, and run something like this logic (pseudocode):

```
var start = getSelectedStartDate();
var end = getSelectedEndDate(); //you'll need to write these functions, but you get the idea
if (end < start) {
  // set the end date field to the selected start date
  $("#end-date").dpSetSelected(start); //not sure if this is the only thing you have to do, but again, you get the idea
}
```

So the idea here is that if ever the end date falls before the start date when the user selects a date in either field, the start date will be placed in the end date field.

Comment: Hello Brandon. thanks for your answer. This certainly will work, but I am trying to simply execute $('#end-date').dpSetStartDate on page load rather than just when a user triggers $('#start-date').bind('dpClosed', function(e, selectedDates) {. Does this make sense? Sorry I am not very good at jQuery.